# Why was my account suspended on SO?

Tags: support, account-suspension

Firstly, I'm not sure if this is the correct place but as I have been suspended on (meta) SO I can't make a meta post there. But, ***please***, understand my perspective and read through the post contextually.

I made [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368079/why-was-my-comment-removed-from-this-question) post on meta SO and I noticed that on the linked post that I was talking about on that meta SO post the OP had responded to my question on the SO question and not the meta SO question. So, instead of responding to the OP who was "snarky" in their tone in that comment (a moderator can confirm by displaying the comment) I flagged it for moderators attention with the reason being something along the lines of:

> This comment should be on the linked meta post, if I mention it, it'll just escalate the situation.

For some reason, the original question (that was being discussed about on meta SO) was locked, my flag was classed as helpful *and* I was put on a suspension so that I can "cool down".

I did the correct thing, instead of escalating the situation and engaging with the OP. I flagged their comment and now, *I'm* being punished?

What is going on here?

**Update #1**

I received no notification but an email to where I should direct my response but it is a dead link?

> This email was sent from an unmonitored account. Do not reply directly to this email; if you feel this message is incorrect, please respond on Stack Overflow here: https://stackoverflow.com/users/message/46634#46634.

**Update #2**

My suspension has been removed and a respective meta SO post has been made [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368092/why-was-i-suspended).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is something you should contact SO about.

Comment: @user3956566 they can't post on Meta.SO because they're suspended ...

Comment: @Glorfindel No, but they can respond to a mod message on SO.

Comment: @Glorfindel It shouldn't be posted on *any* meta.  They should be contacting a mod/CM privately.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I've not received one?

Comment: @Script47 You have, on https://stackoverflow.com

Comment: Script47, if you were manually suspended you should have received a message informing you of that. **You can reply to this message** (only once, so make sure you say everything you need to!) to plead your case.

Comment: @Script47 A mod isn't *able* to suspend you without sending a suspension message.

Comment: Where would I be looking? I have no notifications about the suspension.

Comment: @Servy There are edge cases nowadays with automatic suspensions (e.g. when an account is recreated after being destroyed), but it doesn't sound like that's what happened here.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I did have an account merged? Could that be it?

Comment: @Script47 The "moderator private message" should appear in your inbox notifications, like comments etc. do. You should also have got a copy by email, and the email should contain a link to the mod message on-site.

Comment: @Randal'Thor no notifications, but it seems that I've been sent and email.

Comment: I'am asking myself, is it an account suspension for only one offense ? Can the staff tell us more about the rule, as I seen some users got warning, not suspension at first hand for such offence

Comment: @yagmoth555 my more pressing concern is... what actually *is* my offence?

Comment: You were suspended 20ish minutes ago and sent a mod message at that time. It should appear in your notification inbox and at the email address you have associated with your account.

Comment: @Script47 it's simple for me, the OP found you rude. It's like a kid that draw a drawing, if you answer him, 'you better learn to draw', or 'you have some practice to do'. You see the difference in the tone already.

Comment: @Andy I not received a message but an email but the response link is dead?

Comment: did you check your global inbox? https://stackexchange.com/users/2603134/script47?tab=inbox

Comment: This is currently being discussed among Stack Overflow moderators. Your Stack Overflow account has been unsuspended. The best place to discuss this is probably on the Meta.SO question that you asked, which you should have access to once again. The moderator responsible will be able to explain their reasoning there.

Comment: Respective meta SO post [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368092/why-was-i-suspended).